# php query not returning results

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to execute a php query with no results.  I have been trying to get it to work for hours and figure another set of eyes would be helpful.  Here is my script:

```
if(!empty($cLvl))
{
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT lvl" . $cLvl . " 
    FROM buyers WHERE buyer_id = $buyer");

    $comRate = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
print_r($comRate); die;
```

`$buyer` is found by:

```
$result = $conn->query("select source_id from inventory where sku = {$data[$n]['sku']}");
if($result) {$buyer = $result->fetch_assoc();}
```

and `$cLvl` is found by:

```
if($data[$n]['cost'] == 0 || $bookType3['book_type_3'] == "DMG")
{
    $cLvl = null;
}
elseif($bookType['book_code'] == "IE" || $bookType['book_code'] == "AIE")
{
    $cLvl = 3;
}
elseif($cId['condition_id'] == 1 || $cId['condition_id'] == 2 || $cId['condition_id'] == 3 || $cId['condition_id'] == 4 || $follett['class_code'] == "D" || strpos($follett['notes'],"(T)") == true)
{
    $cLvl = 2;
}
elseif($cId['condition_id'] == 5)
{
    $cLvl = 1;
}
```

in my testing `$buyer = 263` and `$cLvl = 3`.  However when I try to find `$comRate`, it returns nothing. If I hard code in the information I get a result, but this is going to run about 250 records and I can't be hardcoding each one.
Where am I going wrong with this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A whole lot is wrong with this code, but what you're asking for is probably that your `$buyer` is an assoc array, you want to use `{$buyer['source_id']}` instead.

Comment: thanks for the info., I tried that and I am still not getting anything out of my print_r($comRate).  Any other thoughts?

Comment: try printing out `"SELECT lvl" . $cLvl . " 
        FROM buyers WHERE buyer_id = $buyer"` ?

Comment: I get SELECT lvl 3 FROM buyers WHERE buyer_id = 263 when I echo"SELECT lvl" . $cLvl . " FROM buyers WHERE buyer_id = $buyer['source_id']" which is the result I need, but that is as far as it is going.

Comment: What is this space between `lvl` and `3`?